# Extract Value From Pandas Dataframe Based On Condition in Another Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to develop some code that extracts the power price when a power plant starts up.  To give an example refer to the following data frame.

```
data = {
  'Power_Price':  [10, 11,15, 33, 50, 10, 12, 20, 17],
  'Plant_Ops_1': [0, 0, 10, 10, 10, 0, 0, 10, 10],
  'Plant_Ops_2': [0, 0, 0, 50, 50, 0, 0, 0, 0]
}

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['Power_Price','Plant_Ops_1','Plant_Ops_2'])
```

Based on this I aiming to develop some code that would store in a dataframe the power price when the plant ops columns transitions from 0 to a number greater than 0 (i.e. when the power plant starts).  In the case of the data above the output would look something along the lines of:

```
data_out = {
  'Plant': ['Plant_Ops_1', 'Plant_Ops_1', 'Plant_Ops_2'],
  'Power_price': [15, 20, 33]
}

df_out = pd.DataFrame (data_out, columns = ['Plant','Power_price'])
```

Hopefully this makes sense.  Certainly welcome any advice or guidance you are able to provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with filter rows with shifted per groups equal `0` and also greater like `0` in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df.melt('Power_Price', var_name='Plant')

df = df[df.groupby('Plant')['value'].shift().eq(0) & df['value'].gt(0)].drop('value',axis=1)
print (df)
    Power_Price        Plant
2            15  Plant_Ops_1
7            20  Plant_Ops_1
12           33  Plant_Ops_2
```

Last if necessary change order of columns:

```
df = df[["Plant", "Power_Price"]]
```

Comment: Thanks jezrael. Answer worked perfectly.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
df = df.melt(id_vars='Power_Price')

df[(df['value'] > df['value'].shift()) & (df['variable'] == df['variable'].shift())]

    Power_Price     variable  value
2            15  Plant_Ops_1     10
7            20  Plant_Ops_1     10
12           33  Plant_Ops_2     50
```

Comment: Thanks Andreas for the help.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I've understood your question right:

```py
df = df.melt(id_vars="Power_Price")
x = df["value"].eq(0)
x = df.groupby((x != x.shift()).cumsum()).head(1)
x = x[x["value"] > 0].rename(columns={"variable": "Plant"})[
    ["Plant", "Power_Price"]
]
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
          Plant  Power_Price
2   Plant_Ops_1           15
7   Plant_Ops_1           20
12  Plant_Ops_2           33
```

Comment: Thanks Andrej, yes you have understood the question and answer seems to work.  Appreciate the help.